# How to connect Google Sheets to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, google-sheets

I have a Google Form that dumps responses into a Google Sheets file. I need to pipeline these responses to MongoDB. Can someone give me some info on where I should start? I want the responses to be taken from the Google Sheet and put into MongoDB. I'm looking to do this in Python (Although I'm new to it). I've never had a task like this and I'm super eager to conquer it! Thanks for any insight you can give!

Answer (score 3):

> I need to pipeline these responses to MongoDB

If the MongoDB is hosted in [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), you could utilise [MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) to save data from [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/) to MongoDB.

See:

- [Blog: Stitching Sheets using MongoDB Stitch to create API data in Google Sheets](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/stitching-sheets-using-mongodb-stitch-to-create-an-api-for-data-in-google-sheets)
- [Gist: Google Sheets Script](https://gist.github.com/mrlynn/0e2904376cd9e893ae5cec7207e5bcee)
- [GitHub: Stitch App](https://github.com/mrlynn/stitching-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Google Sheet files and use a library called `openpyxl`, you can interact directly with the `.xlsx` files from a Python script.

From there, you should be able to convert rows in the spreadsheet to Python dictionary objects, and pipe those objects right into MongoDB using `pymongo` or the like.

Sounds like a useful tool! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Realm is the answer. With Realm, you can create webhooks. And then add some javascript code to the webhook that decides on how to respond whenever a request hits the webhook.

A simple query webhook will look like this

```
exports = async function(payload, response) { 
  
  // Connect the context with atlas
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
    
  // connect with db and collection
  const database = mongodb.db('database_name');
  const collection = database.collection('collection_name')
  
  const query = {} // Add your query here.

  const result = await collection.find(query)
  return result;
  
};
```

And then from the spreadsheet, you can do a UrlFetchApp query to bring in all the data to the spreadsheet.

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        'webhookURL', 
        {
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          "muteHttpExceptions": true
        }
      );
Logger.log(response)
```

There is an addon for Google sheets called mongoSheet that can do all CRUD ops from the spreadsheet. The addon also connects with a webhook endpoint for all the operations. See docs here https://www.mongosheet.com/docs/getting-started