# How to connect Google form to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-forms

I want to connect Google form to mongodb i.e when users submit information through Google form, it should be stored in a mongodb collection. I want to do it in NodeJs. Anyone who have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

SO, you can either use an external or third-party service.

Assuming your interested in creating a service yourself. There's few ways you would be able to accomplish sharing data.

### Approach ONE:

Firstly, once you create a form you can either create a Google App Script function to handle this data or you can setup a default Google Sheet where data would be stored after the form is submitted. This can be achieved below:

#### Access Script Editor

[image: Access Script Editor]

#### Pass data to default Google Excel Sheet

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en

Once done you can either create a Google App Script to send data to your DB. Though, as you can imagine sending data out this way is pretty risky. Though, if you want to give it a wack.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-MongoDB-to-Google-Sheets?share=1

### Second Approach:

Use MongoDB Atlas which can integrate external data sources. This question has also occurred here

[How to connect Google Sheets to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603692/how-to-connect-google-sheets-to-mongodb)

### Side Bar:

If your just interested creating or generating reports. You can use Google Data Studio, it's a free service provided by google. You can setup / connect to data pipelines from internal / external data sources and generate reports. If you are trying to accomplish this then you'll have to create create a default sheet for your form. Then access the Google Data Studio and then connect to your sheet.

https://datastudio.google.com/